# Change NSMutableArray from subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have main view controller that contain an `NSMutableArray`. I want to open a subview with stepper to change quantity of a product included in that `NSMutableArray`.

How can I access to the `NSMutableArray` from subview and change an object inside it?

Comment: Please avoid ALLCAPS.

Answer (score 0):

In your SubView class make a property of class `NSMutableArray` as

```
@interface SubViewClass : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;

@end
```

Now in your main view controller when calling this SubView you can assign your `NSMutableArray` instance into SubView `array`;

```
subViewInstance.array = mainControllerArray;
```

Now you can modify this array the way you want in your SubView Class.

Comment: no work, i make an:  NSLog(@"%d", _array.count); in the subview and is empty but i make the same before call subview an is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Create a modal class. Then assign all the data to it and access that modal class from your other subview class.